# Text on arrow: sloped text on arrow with corner

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-node

Total beginner here, and trying to figure out tikz.
When I have a construct like this:

```
\draw [arrow] (node1) node[sloped] {Some text} |-  (node2);
```

I end up with something line this (Sorry for the bas ASCII-Art...):

```
|--->
|
Some Text
```

How do I get "Some Text" so be vertical, and on the vertical bit of the arrow?
I had been hoping for [sloped], but that failed.

To Clarify, because clearly I explained badly:
I want the Text to be ON the vertical line, just sideways, that is, with "Text" being indeed slanted instead of being stacked.:

```
T|--->
e|
x|
t|
```

Comment: Thank you all! All the posts taught me more, and you all got an upvote :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

an alternative with use of option `sloped`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->] (1,1)  |-  (3,2) node[at start,left,sloped] {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:** after your editing of question it seems that you looking for something else:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->] (1,1) |-  (3,2) node[pos=0.25,above,sloped] {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

observe the relative position `0.25`: it is smaller than `0.5` which indicate the corner on the line. values equal or great than `0.5` put texto on horisontal part of line.

in case that you have simple straight line, the code is even simpler:

```
  \draw [->] (0,0) -- node[above,sloped] {Some text} (0,2) ;
```

or equivalantly

```
  \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[midway,above,sloped] {Some text};
```

where `midway` has the same affect as `pos=0.5`. results are in the both cases the same:

[image]

for further details see tikz & pgf manual, page 237.

Comment: I was ready to update with this ` \draw [->] (1,1) |-  (3,2) node[pos=0.2,anchor=east,sloped,xshift =-0.3cm] {Some text} ;` but I think it belongs to your answer now which can show these other kind of approach. (Also shows that the things I say about xshift-yshift in my answer are not really correct) +1

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways with rotating (I think this is what you are looking for):

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->] (1,1) node[anchor=east,rotate=90] {Some text} |-  (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw [->] (1,1) node[yshift=-1cm,rotate=90] {Some text} |-  (3,2);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comments:

**A) Why 90 and not -90?**

-Because angles are counterclockwise

**B) Why east and not south?**

-Because the anchor will be called before rotating by 90 degrees (counterclockwise):

Compile next example to see it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
  \draw[->] (A)|-(3,2);
  \only<1>{\node[opacity=0.3] at (A) {\color{red}Some text};
    \node at (-3,0){Without options};
  }
  \only<2>{\node[opacity=0.6,anchor=east] at  (A) {\color{red}Some text};
    \node at (-3,0){Anchor=east: called};}
    \only <3> {\node[anchor=east,rotate=90,opacity=1] at (A) {\color{red}Some text};
    \node at (-3,0){Rotated (around A)};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

If you try to explain the positions with different order (opposite) you will see that the explanation "fails".

**C) What about yshift?**

-yshift is **(Edit:almost always ->e.g.: one exception is a x or yshift in @Zarko's answer)** always referred on the vertical axis if we don't rotate the whole tikzpicture

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want the text to be along the line:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node at (0,0) (nodeA) {A};
    \coordinate (nodeB) at (0,2);
    \node at (2,2) (nodeC) {C};

    \draw[thick,->] (nodeA) -- (nodeB) node [midway, above, sloped] (TextNode) {Text} -- (nodeC);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `sloped` argument will work for angled lines as well:

```
\draw[thick,->] (nodeA) -- (nodeC) node [midway, above, sloped] (TextNode) {Text};
```

will produce the output:

[image]